# ayuda con login en php

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero realizar un login con un registro previo, asi que buscando me encontré con algunos tutoriales, y este es seria el código para logearse:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php

$host_db = "localhost";
$user_db = "root";
$pass_db = "123";
$db_name = "proyecto_pre";
$tbl_name = "usuario";

$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

if ($conexion->connect_error) {
 die("La conexion falló: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user = '$username'" ;

$result = $conexion->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
 $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

 if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {

 $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 $_SESSION['start'] = time();
 $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);

 echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['username'];
 echo "<br><br><a href=panel-control.php>Panel de Control</a>";

 } else {
 echo "Username o Password estan incorrectos.";

 echo "<br><a href='login.php'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
 }
}
mysqli_close($conexion)
?>
```

Sin embargo a la hora de ingresar el usuario y el password de mi base de datos, el codigo me arroja el mensaje "Username o Password estan incorrectos." , y cuando ingreso un usuario y pass incorrecto el archivo checklogin.php(el codigo login) se muestra en blanco.

Alguien sabe cual es el error? Soy nuevo en php.

Comment: Vamos viendo primero que datos envías y que datos tienes en la bd, porque no comienzas debugueando los password, coloca un `var_dump($password);` y también para `var_dump($row['password']);` con esto vamos a conocer los valores de ambos datos.

Comment: Aparte de eso, este código es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Deberías utilizar sentencias preparadas en lugar de SQL dinámicos, y sanear las entradas de usuario antes de utilizarlas/guardarlas

Comment: El código me funciona sin problemas en local, esto podría ser un error con los valores en la tabla

Comment: Hola, you tengo un tutorial en my pagina de github para hacer un foro de mensajes en php es mejor que lo que estas haciendo porque ya las funciones como mysqli son consideradas mal practica echale un vistazo https://github.com/rojobo/PHP7MessageBoard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero revisa bien el código, ya que la funcion password_verify recibe 2 parámetros, el valor(password) y la encriptación del mismo.

```
boolean password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )
```

Comment: OP está pasándole dos parámetros a `password_verify`

Comment: Si, pero ese parámetro no es el hash!  $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: Eso no lo sabemos. Raphael puede haber guardado el hash en la base de datos y entonces sí es el hash; si no, entonces estás en lo correcto y ese es el problema

Comment: Pues entonces que revise esto y que notifique: $row['password']

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo que hagas la encriptación del password compruebes los password encriptados directamente